# Amortization of increasing payment annuity

Tags: finance

> A loan is repaid with $20$ increasing annual installments of $1,2,3,· · ·
>  ,20$. The payments begin one year after the loan is made. Find the
> principal contained in the $10$th payment, if the annual interest rate
> is 4%.

Correct Answer: $4.88$

My work:

We need to solve $P_{10} = R_{10}-I_{10} = 10-(0.04)B_9$, where $R_t$=payment amt at time t, $I_t$=amt of interest charged at time t, $B_t$ = outstanding loan balance at time t

Using the prospective method,
$$
B_9 = 10a_{\bar{10}|} + 1\cdot \frac{a_{\bar{10}|}-10\nu^{10}}{.04}
$$
However, plugging result into final equation gives an answer that is around 5.4. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I don't see where your calculations reflect the increasing payment stream.

Comment: in the expression for the prospective method